# Open source software library for camera serial transmission?

Tags: open-source, camera, usb, protocol, serial-port

I am looking for an equivalent to the [Camera Serial Interface](https://mipi.org/specifications/csi-3), which is a protocol used to communicate from a photo or camera device to a reception such as an USB port, using a serial communication.

This protocol is apparently made for companies, so I am looking for an equivalent software library that would be dedicated to transmit camera data fast on serial interface, which would be open source or plug-and-play (doubt this last is possible).

Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please note we recommend software here, not protocols.

Comment: But it's a good question :-) and you can make it on topic by rewording the question to asking us for a software library.

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica I have edited the question but am not sure: is a software library close to a protocol? A protocol is an hardware thing?

Comment: I have been a software engineer for a few decades now, coding protocols. You ought to be able to find a software library